# Prevent double click on submit button while not supressing validationGroup

Tags: javascript, asp.net

in an asp.net application when I click several times on one button it submits the request multiple times. When I tried to implement a javascript function in order to make it submit the request only once. That solution worked, but unfortunately it suppresses the validationgroup, in other words it made the validation components of the form non operational. I would like a solution that prevents double clicking and keeps the validation of my form operational.

Here is the javascript funtion that I used to prevent the double clicking

```
                var submit = 0;
                function CheckDouble() {
                    if (++submit > 1) {
                       return false;
                    }
                }
```

Here is my button component

```
    <asp:Button ID="cmdSaveExpense" runat="server" Text="140" tooltip="Save and close" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="NewExpense" CssClass="button2" OnClick="return CheckDouble()" />
```

Here are the validators that are suppressed

```
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AmtRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAmt" ErrorMessage="* An amount is required"  ValidationGroup="NewExpense"  Display="Dynamic" />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="cboCat" ErrorMessage="" Text="* An expense type is required" ValidationGroup="NewExpense" Display="Dynamic"  />
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be an `OnClientClick`...?

Comment: You can use one function of juery function http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

An old fashion way to do this is to hide the button on the first click, show an animated gif on the same place - and make the button re-appear when the request is done.

This will keep everything intact asp.net wise, will disabling double posting by the user. You can use diff javascript methods to achieve this - but keep in mind it has to run very fast. Native works best. Do not remove the element from the DOM, just hide/show both with css.

It's been years since I had to do this, but I remember it well b/c I had a lot of trouble with double submits. This solution worked as a charm.